# SHAP explanation for the inputs with different types in CNN models

Tags: shap

I have a question to use SHAP to explain the result of my CNN model.  My CNN models take 2 inputs with different types. One is an image, and another is a feature vector.  I trained and tested the model by taking both of them into account.  No problem with establishing the model.

When I tried to use SHAP to explain the result for those two inputs simultaneously, it doesn't work.  I actually have tried both deepexplainer and gradientexplainer. The error I got is below:

> File "", line 1, in
> shap_values = explainer.shap_values([x_test[:3], feature_test[:3]])
>
> File "C:\Users\kaz10003\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-> > packages\shap\explainers\deep_init_.py", line 119, in shap_values
> return self.explainer.shap_values(X, ranked_outputs, output_rank_order)
>
> File "C:\Users\kaz10003\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-> packages\shap\explainers\deep\deep_tf.py", line 284, in shap_values
> diffs = model_output[:, l] - self.expected_value[l] - > output_phis[l].sum(axis=tuple(range(1, output_phis[l].ndim)))
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'

Anybody has any idea to know if SHAP supports such implementation? Here is my code:

```
n_features = 10
input_feat = Input((n_features,))
input_tensor = Input(shape=(50,60, 1))

c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (input_tensor)
c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c3)
c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c3)
p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

f_repeat = RepeatVector(6*7)(input_feat)
f_conv = Reshape((6, 7, n_features))(f_repeat)
p3_feat = concatenate([p3, f_conv], -1)

c3 = Flatten()(p3_feat)
c3 = Dense(512)(c3)
outputs = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(c3)
model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor, input_feat], outputs=[outputs])

model.summary()

explainer = shap.GradientExplainer(model, [x_train, feature_train])
shap_values = explainer.shap_values([x_test[:3], feature_test[:3]])
```

Comment: feature is a vector of size (10,1), x is a image of (64,64,1). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found below post showing the capability of SHAP to explain the results with two inputs. The only difference in my case is the different dimension of inputs.  The example show below has two input images with same size.   https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/notebooks/gradient_explainer/Multi-input%20Gradient%20Explainer%20MNIST%20Example.ipynb